# Is there any particular term to mention the small ditches on the road?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Is there any particular term to mention the small ditches on the road ?

Comment: Can you provide more information/context? A picture might help in answering your question.

Comment: You may be interested in [“Barrow Pit.” Western American Term for Ditch](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316638/barrow-pit-western-american-term-for-ditch) as asked on ELU. But for most practical purposes, ***a ditch is a ditch***, regardless of whether it's large or small, or whether it runs alongside a road. Unless you're actually thinking of [***potholes***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pothole) - *depressions or hollows in a road surface caused by wear or subsidence.*

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking about a [pothole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pothole)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Small "ditches" in the road are called

> potholes

[image]
<sub>(source: [huffpost.com](http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1018002/images/o-CHICAGO-POTHOLE-SEASON-facebook.jpg))</sub>

This picture is still considered to be a "pothole" even though a "ditch" tends to have length and a "hole" is round.

"Ditches" tend to occur *alongside* a road, not *in* a road, often for drainage purposes

[image]
<sub>(source: [roadex.org](http://www.roadex.org/wp-content/uploads/elearning/drainage/5/5229d.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You may mean gutters -- specifically, [street gutters](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_gutter). Not all street gutters have gratings that lead to underground sewers. Many appear as very shallow ditches. Their purpose is to control rain runoff.

Gutters are normally parallel to the street, but at intersections (especially intersections with a downhill slope or grade) these shallow depressions for controlling rain runoff may continue downhill across the intersection, perpendicular to the other road. Driving across them is like driving across very shallow ditches.

[image: Shallow street gutters for rain runoff]